# How to force the DropDownList to take both value and text of the source?

Tags: asp.net

I've struggling for hours now with this issue. I have a list that I keep in the Session

```
Session["AllDev"] = taskData.DisplayAllDevelopers();
```

I use it later this way.

```
_ddlAllDev.DataSource = (ListItemCollection)Session["AllDev"];
_ddlAllDev.DataBind();
```

**DisplayAllDevelopers()** method returns a ListItemCollection. Each ListItem contains the **ID** of the Developer as Value and the **name of the Developer** as Text. But When I check the items collection, I find that the DropDownList has both the value and the text set to the name of the devoloper. Is there a way to force the DropDownList to keep the Value and the Text as the source is?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also try this

```
_ddlAllDev.DataValueField = "ID";
_ddlAllDev.DataTextField= "DevName";
_ddlAllDev.DataSource = (ListItemCollection)Session["AllDev"];
_ddlAllDev.DataBind();
```

Comment: It looks like the RadioButtonList also needed the same setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
YourDDL.DataValueField = "ID";
YourDDL.DataTextField= "DevName";
```